# casting void* to struct * in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef  struct {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
} Struct_A;

void* malloc_(size_t s, byte* heap, int *next) {
    int old = *next;
    *next = *next + s;
    return heap + old;
}

void f(Struct_A *sa, byte* heap, int *next) {
    sa = (Struct_A*) malloc_(8, heap, next);
    sa->a = 10;
    sa->b = 20;
}

int main() {
    byte *heap = new byte[1000];
    int next;
    next = 0;

    Struct_A *sa;
    sa = (Struct_A*) malloc_(8, heap, &next);
    sa->a = 100;
    sa->b = 200;

    cout << sa->a << endl;


    Struct_A *sb;
    f(sb, heap, &next);
    cout<< sb->a <<endl;


    return 0;

}
```

the code works well for sa but not for sb!!!
function f() does exactly the same thing the three code lines after "Struct_A *sa;" does. Any idea what is wrong with function f()?

Comment: This is not C, but C++! In C you should not cast `void *` to another pointer type

Comment: @Olaf The other way not C++ but C

Comment: @DieterLücking: `cout<< sb->a <<endl` or `new byte[1000];` are C?

Comment: You pas sb, but you should pass a pointer to sb and declare f to have an extra indirection

Comment: Either change the code to C or change the tag and text to C++. These are different languages.

Comment: @Olaf Just an alibi to make it C++

Comment: @DieterLücking: Nope. This is about memory allocation, so thre is a difference. It also targets one of the differences between the two languages.

Comment: Why was the C++ tag removed? `namespace` and `new` and `cout` are C++. They are not C.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I agree that this is a C++ question. But OP clearly asks about `C`. There is a meta somewhere to ask for clarification instead of removing the tag (about which I disagree).

Comment: @Olaf I rolled it back to both tags, but it's been changed since.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Just leave it at that. Imo the tag is correct and OP seems not to be interested to clarify, so why should we care?

Answer (score 0):

You pas sb, but you should pass a pointer to sb and declare f to have an extra indirection:

```
void f(Struct_A **sa, byte* heap, int *next) {
    *sa = (Struct_A*) malloc_(8, heap, next);
    (*sa)->a = 10;
    (*sa)->b = 20;
}

int main() {

    Struct_A *sb;
    f(&sb, heap, &next);
```

Comment: Since it's C++, just use a reference:  `void f( Struct_A &sa,...)`  Or even better, just *return* the pointer:  `Struct_A *f(...)`

Comment: @Andrew Henle, could be fine for C++, but I answered in C. Should work in C++ too, wouldn't it? (I hate those rerferences as you forget it is acually a pointer...)

Comment: Someone edited the question to remove C++ and replace it with C.  No idea why, as `new`, `#include <iostream>`, and `namespace` are all clearly C++ and not C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well,  I'm working with c99 and OpenCl although I posted the c++ code.